# Pipe rbd export comand to tar to create compressed export

Tags: ceph

Is it possible to pipe the output of `rbd export` directly to something else like `tar` to create a compressed archive of the .img file without having to write to disk first?

Something like

`rbd export Pool/image | tar -czvf image.img.zst`

Or do I just have to use some disk as a middleman to create the archive?

Comment: Does it have to be `tar`? Would something like `rbd export pool/image - | gzip -k9 > rbdexport.gzip` work for you?

Comment: @eblock not necessarily.  Just a way to trim all the empty space in the image, which is basically any archive format.  That worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to sparsify the archived image during `rbd export` you can use:

```
rbd export pool/image - | gzip -k9 > rbdexport.gzip
```

To sparsify the image on the fly without having to export it there's a `sparsify`command for that, for example if you can't trim the space from within the VM (I assume you're using rbd for virtual machines):

```
rbd sparsify pool/image
```

Comment: Actually they're a kubernetes PV backend.  This is just a way of having backups of the images not within my existing storage infrastructure.  Though how would I import the compressed image?  It seems to require a file to do `rbd import`.

Comment: The import works the other way around, of course. But you'll have to unzip it first before importing it. The import works like this: `rbd import <OPTIONS> <LOCAL_IMAGE> <POOL>/<IMAGE>`.